# How did Sam and her mother come to file a paternity suit against Reacher in Jack Reacher 2?

Tags: jack-reacher-2

In *Jack Reacher 2*, a major part of the plot involves Reacher being informed that a woman has filed a paternity suit against him with regards to a 15-year old daughter he was unaware of. The daughter, Sam, says that this was her idea, and that she encouraged her mother to do it in the hopes of getting money.

Near the very end, it turns out Reacher has never met her mother, and they don't even recognize each other.

This begs the question: why on earth did they file against Jack Reacher? What connection did he have to them?

As far as I can tell, there is no way they even would have known he existed: evidently he's never met them, so he should just be one of 7 billion anonymous people on the planet. So how did they hear of him and come to file a suit against him if they have zero connection to him? How they would have ever even heard his name?

Had Sam's mother known another person whose name was *also* Jack Reacher?

Comment: (I can't comment on the film b/c I haven't seen it yet, but in the books, JR is almost Bond-like in the quantity of his liaisons with the ladies, and never a single mention of birth control ;)

Comment: It's easy to dismiss it as she's not his, but the hint to it several times in the movie by giving Sam many similar qualities Reacher possesses.... uncommon observational skills, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In the novel:**

Jack Reacher: Never Go Back, of which the film is based on, the villains know that Reacher has been calling Turner leading up to them discovering she is learning too much and have her arrested. So when he shows up they have already lined up a fake paternity suit and a fake charge of aggravated assault against a suspect from a long old case. They know he is an accomplished investigator who has become a drifter, and their objection is to convince him to disappear again.

**In the Movie:**

Again Reacher has been calling Turner (of which there is likely a log) leading up to Turner's guys finding out something about the villains operation.

Samantha says that it was her idea to have her mother file a paternity suit, but her mother has never told her the name of her father. It is believable that these higher ups (like Morgan) simply pulled the top paternity suit off a stack of cases and changed the name to Jack Reacher. Again, as soon as he arrives he is being followed, and they have this suit lined up hoping to convince him to just disappear.

Since the mother obviously has never seen Reacher (and vise versa) and Samantha didn't know who he was either, it is not logical to think they actually put Jack Reacher on their paternity suit.

**Back to the novel:**

In the novel they actually did a little research and found a woman who had been stationed at the same place as him 15 years ago, and provided a fake birth certificate and other documents to make it look like Reacher really could have been the father.

Just like the movies though, Reacher's memory is near perfect, and he is has no recollection of the name or the face of the woman he supposedly had a child with.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. So the real answer is, specifically with regards to the movie, "They didn't explain it and you have to guess what happened."

Comment: Who knows what might be revealed in deleted scenes or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the explaination would be that Reacher is indeed her father and the waitress was just random person Samantha chose to confront him. And why she did so? Because she knew that Jack was living a dangerous life and like all superheroes their enemy always get back at them through their belived ones. Her last experience showed it to her and she doesn't want to be a burden to Reacher or put herself in danger if words get out that Reacher has a daughter. At the last scene you could see that Samantha has feelings for Reacher and it is more than those for just a guy who save her life. She knows he is her father but choose not to let him know and worry about her. I think that fits more and is more convenient for a guy like Jack Reacher.